# Getting error - 'could not find a writer'while giving imshow, imwrite command opencv

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I am a beginner at opencv and python.
I have just installed opencv2.4.9 and enthought canopy-32bit. I am getting error for the following:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('Lena.jpg')
cv2.imwrite('Mypic',image)
```

This is what I get:

```
c:\users\nam\appdata\local\temp\tmpokspbt.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 image = cv2.imread('Lena.jpg')
----> 5 cv2.imwrite('Mypic',image)

error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp:275: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function cv::imwrite_
```

Answer (score 34):

you need to give an extension to imwrite(), so it knows, how to save(compress) it.

```
cv2.imwrite('Mypic.png',image)
# jpg,bmp,png,ppm,pgm,tiff supported 'out-of-the-box,
# webp,jp2 depending on if you compiled in the resp. 3rd party support
# no gif or tga.
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure you have the image type within the string you give to the imwrite().
imwrite() dose not have a default method to save, thus it is required within the name you give to it.
instead of : 
`cv2.imwrite('Mypic',image)`
you need to write :

```
cv2.imwrite('Mypic.The_format_you_want_to_save',image)
```

As an example:

```
cv2.imwrite('Mypic.jpg',image)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an extension for the output file like .jpg, .png, etc based on the application.

For example in this case you could use,

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('Lena.jpg')
cv2.imwrite('Mypic.jpg',image)
```

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this problem by simply adding the extension '.jpg' etc at the end of the image and it worked for me!