# could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'cv::imwrite_'

Tags: python, opencv

I am facing error while defining a function to add border in an image

```
import cv2

def im_border(path: str, output: str = "output.png"):
              im1 = cv2.imread(path)
              border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
                            im1, 20, 20, 20, 20, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = [128, 128, 128])
              cv2.imwrite(output, border)

              return None 
              
im_border(r'C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\8a4c4b2b47cdcbb6d359140081f63478.jpg',r'C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop')
```

Why this is giving an error
The error is as follows -

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:730: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'cv::imwrite_'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting your default value `output.png` with `C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop` which does not have a valid file ending. Try

```
C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\output.png
```

as output in

```
im_border(r'C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\8a4c4b2b47cdcbb6d359140081f63478.jpg',r'C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\output.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the correct extension to `.imwrite(,)`.
The filename `output` must contain a path with the correct extension. (ex : `.jpg`, `.png`)

Please refer to [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291451/getting-error-could-not-find-a-writerwhile-giving-imshow-imwrite-command-op).